# getting error while starting the server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat6

'Publishing to Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost...' has encountered a problem
Publishing failed with multiple errors
Could not replace with temp file C:\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\temp\tmp63750.jsp.
Could not replace with temp file C:\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\temp\tmp63751.MF.
Could not replace with temp file C:\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\temp\tmp63752.class.
Could not replace with temp file C:\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\temp\tmp63753.class.
Could not replace with temp file C:\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\temp\tmp63754.class.
Could not replace with temp file C:\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\temp\tmp63755.xml.
Could not replace with temp file C:\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\temp\tmp63756.html.

I'm getting the above error while starting the tomcat in eclipse

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1. Remove project from server.
2. Delete tomcat server from eclipse and add server again.

Comment: Thank you Vinay. I tried this now i'm not getting error while starting the server. But getting the same error while running jsp file. How to solve this issue? Because of this error, I'm not able to run any program on server. I deleted the server in c:/programfiles and reinstalled again. Also i have deleted the eclipse and reinstalled again. but still getting the same error :(

Comment: As per below link it suggest that to overcome this error (not sure that your problem is same as this or not, give a try), you have to make sure that Eclipse workspace and the server are should not on different file systems or partitions. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=210025 and give one more try to changing workspace to new folder if above link not related to ur issue.

Comment: yes Vinay I'm getting the same error which is mentioned on the given link. But the suggested solution didnt solve the problem. I did set my eclipse workspace and server under a same folder. Still getting the same error. Any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me now. I have changed the location of eclipse workspace to another directory and placed the server